# Showing $[N\cap G_i,G]\le G_{i-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a nilpotent group with a central series $1=G_0\le G_1\le …\le G_n=G$ and $N$ be a non trivial normal subgroup of $G$.

1. Show that $[N\cap G_i,G]\le G_{i-1}$ for each $i=1,...,n$.
2. Deduce $[N\cap G_i,G]=1$ for each $i=1,...,n$.

My attempt:
$[N\cap G_i,G]\le [G_{i},G]\le G_{i}$ and $[N\cap G_i,G]\le [N,G]\le N$. So $[N\cap G_i,G]\le [G_{i},G]\le G_{i}\cap N$.
How to proceed from here? Thank you.

Comment: It's a central series so $[G_i,G] \le G_{i-1}$. Part 2 is not true.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true consider the product of two non commutative nilpotent groups $G=H_1\times H_2$. Let $N=H_1\times \{1\}$, $N$ is not trivial and normal. $[H_1,H_1]\neq 1$, implies that $[H_1,H_1]\times\{1\}\subset [N\cap G_1,G ]\neq 1$.